# Does the Iron Monk's Bastion Stance conflict with Pummeling Style?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk

The [Monk of the Sacred Mountain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/monk-of-the-sacred-mountain/) text makes no mention of the Bastion Stance being treated as a combat [style feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/style-feats/). I am questioning it though because the Iron Limb Defense mentions complementing the Bastion Stance almost as if it were.

If I were to take [Pummeling Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style), would I have to switch to a Pummeling stance from my Bastion Stance and choose one over the other? Or is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can have both

Bastion Stance, despite having "Stance" in the name, is not a Combat Style.

The trigger condition for Bastion Stance is

> If the monk starts and ends his turn in the same space

So long as you meet this condition, it shouldn't matter what other actions you take on your turn.

It wasn't directly asked, but since you mentioned it in your question: the same is true for Iron Limb Defense as it has the same trigger condition. Simply start and end your turn in the same square.